# value of TextField input from event target in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to console log the value of the TextField input in material ui while using typescript in react. But I got `undefined` in the console. I tried several solutions, but none worked.

Here's my code:

```
const HomePage: React.FC = () => {

    const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log((e.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement).value);
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xl">
            <div style={{width: '385px', margin: 'auto'}}>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => {onSubmit(e)}}>
                    <Stack direction='row' spacing={1}>
                        <CustomTextField placeholder="Enter name" label="Name" type="text" variant="outlined" name="name" />
                        <Button type="submit" variant="contained" size='large'>Add</Button>
                    </Stack>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have conflated two examples on dealing with input values to get an incorrect solution.

Because the onSubmit handler is attached to the form, it will have access to all the input values within that form within `event.target.elements[..].value`, of which there could be many. You can then select the value you want using the name attribute of the input, in this case you have set it to `name="name"` so your onSubmit handler can access it as such:

```
    const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.elements.name.value);
    };
```

Edit: you could also access the input directly by dropping the `.elements`, so `e.target.name.value` would also work.

---

What I think you may have confused this with is an onChange handler attached to an input, such as `<CustomTextField />`, where because there is only one input the event object is able to hold the value at `event.target.value`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your time.. I tried your solution, but it tells me property name doesn't exist. And when I tried elements, I got property elements doesn't exist.
Thanks

Comment: I found the solution, thanks

Comment: hi @user10033434 I tested my code and it does work to resolve undefined being returned, on the assumption that `<CustomTextField />` is correctly passing the name prop down to the underlying input component.

This issue you might be seeing is a typescript error which I wasn't trying to solve, should have been clearer that that might have been there. Glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstanding, and thanks again for your time.. i really appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the value by using the following:

```
const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = (e.currentTarget.elements.namedItem('name') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    };
```